# how can I condition a variable on my colorscheme?

Tags: vimscript, colorscheme, highlight

I use different colorschemes depending on the color of my xterm.    Some of them (in particular `torte`) set the background color to black, others leave the background color the same as the xterm color. The colorscheme is specified as an environment variable for each xterm.

I also use the lines

```
set hlsearch
hi Search ctermfg=white  ctermbg=black cterm=NONE
hi IncSearch ctermfg=Black  ctermbg=lightyellow cterm=bold,underline,reverse
```

which highlight with a black background my search term.   Obviously this doesn't help me when the background is already black.    So I'd like to condition the above lines (specifically `ctermfg`) on the value of the environment variable which specifies my color scheme.  (Specifically, whether this value is `torte`)      Should be easy but I'm hopeless with vim syntax.    Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice to you is make your own color schemes that incorporate your versions of `Search` and `IncSearch`. But you if you really don't want to do that you could probably do the following:

```
if g:colors_name == "torte"
...
else
...
endif
```

Please note that this is not guarenteed to work as [this is only a standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419692/1924583) and not a sure fire way to see your color scheme.